# Clicking Xtify notification to launch the android app | Appcelerator

Tags: android, push-notification, titanium, appcelerator, xtify

I've managed to integrate Xtify push notifications with my Titanium app for android.
I receive the notifications but when I click them They don't open anything, just disappear.

This is from my tiapp.xml:

```
<property name="com.activate.gcm.sender_id" type="string">MY_SENDER_ID</property>
<property name="com.activate.gcm.icon" type="int">2130837504</property>
<property name="com.activate.gcm.component" type="string">com.myCompany.myApp/com.myCompany.myApp.myApp</property>
<!-- [package name]/[package name].[activity name] -->
```

And this is the Xtify code in my app.js file:

```
var g = require('xtify_plugin/Globals');
var push = require('xtify_plugin/PushNotificationService');
Ti.App.fireEvent(g.events.APP_OPENED);
```

My sender ID is correct and I receive notifications already. I just wanna know If I missed some code to handle the notifications. I think they should at least open the app on their own.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have the same android:name value in AndroidManifest.xml and your Tiapp.xml gcm component property. This has resolved our issue

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! You can use also commentaries for question where you can give some advises / questions to clarify the problem / etc. Please, use Answers only when you are sure that this answer will help.